# :focus on a img

Tags: css

I have a portfolio that works fine but I'm currently building a CMS for it so that I can simply upload the image and it adds it to the site for me. Before I build it, I'm rebuilding some of the scrappy code and converting the what was a JS powered gallery to a CSS powered one.

I'm trying to achieve this click effect in CSS. http://www.tomdwyerdesign.com/graphics/

I thought I could do it via the :focus selector but I've run into a little problem.

This is the HTML:

```
<a class="tile" href="#">
        <img src="images/thumbs/DLPWD.png" class="dlpwd" />
</a>
```

and this is the CSS:

```
.tile:focus img{
background-image: url("images/large/DLPWD.png");
width: 771px;
height: 600px;
}
```

It doesn't seem to select it properly. Any one know why?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with JS? It looks like your linked gallery is using JS.  JS will probably be better supported than any fancy CSS3 transforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that a link is not necessarily focused when it's clicked, it's focused when you navigate to it. You can do this with the keyboard, or you could add a click handler to the link. Of course at that point, you're back into javascript, but it shows what's happening.

E.g.

```
<a class="tile" href="#" onclick="this.focus()">
    <img src="images/thumbs/DLPWD.png" class="dlpwd" />
</a>
```

Luckily, there is a better solution, and one that doesn't require javascript. If you add a tabindex to the link, clicking it will focus it even if the href is going nowhere. So...

```
<a class="tile" href="#" tabindex="0">
    <img src="images/thumbs/DLPWD.png" class="dlpwd" />
</a>
```

Should do what you want.

(your next problem is going to be that the background-image won't be visible in front of the src image - you're just going to get a stretched version of the thumbnail. But I think that's a different question)

Comment: Links *do* receive focus when activated.

Answer (score 0):

`:focus` is only available on elements that receive keyboard input (i.e. form elements). You could try `:active` but it will only apply the CSS while the mouse button is down.

Comment: actually, :focus is available on links, just not when you click it. If you navigate to the link using the keyboard, the styling will be activated